# Malloc returns null in adt list program

Tags: c, list, null, malloc, adt

I was working on a program with ADT list, queue, etc... Made by various .c and .h files.

I'm showing you a **little extract** of the program, just to let you understand better where is the problem; this little program, however, is compilable and runnable.

The problem is that a simple malloc in a function (something I've always did!), returns NULL, or causes segmentation fault (Visual Studio behavior is different than CodeBlocks for example). The malloc I'm talking about is the one in the InsertTop function.
Here is the short code, **thanks for your help**!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define M 35+1

typedef struct student* Student;
struct student
{
    char name[M];
    char surname[M];
    char number[M];
};


typedef struct node* Node;
struct node
{
    Node prev;
    Student student;
    Node next;
};

typedef struct list* List;
struct list
{
    Node first;
    Node last;
};

/* PROTOTYPES */
List Initialize(List list);
List InsertTop(List list, Student student);
Student PromptStudent(Student student);

/* MAIN */
int main()
{
    /* DECLARATIONS */
    List list = NULL;
    Student student = NULL;

    /* LIST OPERATIONS */
    list=Initialize(list);
    while (0==0)
    {
        student=PromptStudent(student);
        list=InsertTop(list, student);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/* FUNCTIONS */
/* 1 */
List Initialize(List list)
{
    list = malloc(sizeof(List));

    list->first = list->last = NULL;

    return list;
}

/* 2 */
List InsertTop(List list, Student student)
{
    Node p;

    /* THIS LINE CREATES THE ERROR! */
    p = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    /* New node */
    p->prev = NULL;
    p->next = list->first;
    p->student = student;

    /* Update list with new node */
    if (list->first == NULL)
        list->first = list->last = p;
    else
    {
        list->first->prev = p;
        list->first = p;
    }

    printf(" -> Done!\n");

    return list;
}

/* 3 */
Student PromptStudent(Student student)
{
    student = malloc(sizeof(Student));

    printf("Name: "); scanf("%s", student->name);
    printf("Surname: "); scanf("%s", student->surname);
    printf("Number: "); scanf("%s", student->number);

    return student;
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by error you are not even checking whether malloc returned NULL or not and also,you should be allocating memory for sizeof(struct list) not sizeof(struct list *)

Comment: Gopi is right, the same problem exists with Node and Student: malloc(sizeof(Node)) is simply wrong, since Node is declared as node*.

Comment: Btw your initialize function should take no arguments (void).  The argument you are currently passing is unused and quite frankly, confusing.  Similarly, there's no need for InsertTop to return anything because you don't change `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node` is a pointer type. You want to allocate as much memory to a pointer as of the type it is pointing to. This however isn't `Node`, but `struct node` or simply what `p` is pointing to, that is `*p`.

This

```
 p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

shall be

```
 p = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
```

or even better

```
 p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

---

As a general rule: Do not `typedef` pointers, this very easily leads to confusion, as here.

---

Some other issues with your code:

- This `#define M 35+1` shall be `#define M (35+1)`.
- Instead of `while (0==0)` you can do `while (1)`.
- `scanf("%s" ...` shall be `scanf("%35s" ...` to avoid buffer overflows, if the user enters more then 35 `char`s.

Answer (score 0):

Make below suggested changes:
Memory should be allocated for sizeof structure as shown below and not for size of pointer to a structure.This needs to be updated in all the `malloc()` in your program.

```
   list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));

   p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

   student = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was there!

Comment: Np please change your typedef's they might be confusing